# How to add a mean line in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Category=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), 
                 Value=c(10,15,17,8,20,23,19,7), 
                 Time=c("Time1", "Time2", "Time1", "Time3", "Time2", "Time1", "Time3", "Time1"))
```

I am plotting the data as text with geom_text() using the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Value, label=Category)) + 
  geom_text() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

I want to add a line connecting the mean value from Time 1 to Time 3. I have tried with `geom_hline()` but it doesn't work.
I hope to receive some help about this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by creating an object with means for each group and then plotting a line using it as data:

```
means <- df %>% group_by(Time) %>% summarise(mean_val=mean(Value))

ggplot() + 
  geom_text(data=df, mapping = aes(x=Time, y=Value, label=Category)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_line(data=means, mapping=aes(x=Time, y=mean_val, group=1))
```

[image]

Comment: @user21390049, you're most welcome! Glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 4):

Another option to get a line with the means would be to use `stat_summary` with `fun=mean` and `geom="line"`. Additionally, as the variable mapped on `x` is categorical we have to explicitly set the `group` aes using e.g. `group = 1` to get one line connecting the means.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Value, label = Category)) +
  geom_text() +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean, aes(group = 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Stefan! I did try to use stat_summary at first but did not know to add aes(group=1) in the code so it didn't work then :). Again, many thanks!!

Comment: I have to admit, this solution is more elegant. Thanks for the tip!